# Getting undefined value in property angular

Tags: angular, angular12

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to get string data from  shared services in my second component which is receiving value from another component.
So I'm subscribing to the observable to receive the string data from service, after receiving value in the another component I'm storing the value in property as shown below, but can't access the string data stored in property outside of the function..

Please can somebody can guide me with this issue..

**This is the function where I am subscribing to the observable**

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.recieveFiles();
    this.sendAttachment();
  }

  recieveFiles(){
    this._sendFile.getFile$.subscribe(files => {    
      // When this code gets executed it should have the value
      // emitted from the emitting component.
      this.getFiles = files;
       console.log("File:" + this.getFiles);   <- **Here I am getting the string data in console**
      return this.getFiles;
   
    });   
  }

x:any;
  sendAttachment(){
    let y = this.getFiles;
    console.log("String Files:" + y);  **This where I am getting undefined as shown in Screenshot**
  }
```

here are the screenshots
[image]

[image]

Comment: you can only access the value in subscribe, you cannot return from a subscribe.
subscribe is the only scope that can guarantee the files to exist. You need to revisit your knowledge on rxjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
this.recieveFiles(); <-- Begins to receive the file
this.sendAttachment(); <-- Before the file is received, Angular executes this
```

The fix is to wait for the actual file to load before calling `sendAttachment()`, meaning you can do `this.sendAttachment()` inside the subscription:

```
    this._sendFile.getFile$.subscribe(files => {    
      this.getFiles = files;
      this.sendAttachment(); <-- Here's your fix.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`return this.getFiles;` is unnecessary.
Instead of that line, put `this.sendAttachment();`

In your ngAfterViewInit, there are two methods that are being invoked.
recieveFiles -> Which runs a subscription and gets the files.
sendAttachment -> Which does something with the files.

In your implementation the sendAttachment runs before recieveFiles subscription gets the files. hence it was showing as undefined.

Comment: can you explain it properly..  @DevashishSarmah

Comment: Ok then what is the possible way to avoid it and achieve the outcome @Devashish Sarmah

Comment: You can put your sendAttachment method call inside the getFile$ subscription.
Just after this line `this.getFiles = files;` @Ashish_more